# A Javascript regex needed

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string like `'a b xy c pq'`, and I need to write a regex so that the `match()` method returns an array liek this: `['a','b','xy','c','pq']`.

Let's see some examples:

```
>>> 'x y z '.match(/\w{1,3}\s+/g)
['x ', 'y ', 'z ']

>>> 'x y z '.match(/(\w{1,3})\s+/g)
['x ', 'y ', 'z ']
```

As you can see, even when I add parentheses, it returns the same result. I want the result to be **without** the white spaces. Also it'd be nice to not have to add the ending white space in the source string.

Where do you think I can improve this regex to get what I want?

Note that I don't want to use `exec()` because it has to be run multiple times to get all the matches.

Also note that this problem could be easily solved with `split()`

```
>>> 'x y z'.split(/\s/)
['x', 'y', 'z']

>>> "a b xy c pq".split(/\s/)
['a','b','xy','c','pq']
```

But, I need to also validate the string. It should only have a max three characters in each match, and each match should be an alphanumeric word with no special characters. Hence I can not use `split()`, because in that case I'd have to validate each match separately. I want to do it all via a single regex.

The reason I want to do the validation and splitting in a single regex is because I need to do a lot of these within an event, hence I need to make it as fast as possible.

Comment: What's wrong with the fact `exec` has to be run multiple times? Surely you can move it into a _function_ if you want to keep that particular area of your code clean/make it more readable.

Comment: Multiple exec calls amount to lower performance. And don't forget you need to check `lastIndex` in each iteration -- which further degrades speed.

Comment: When `exec` is ongoing it's truthy, when it ends, it gives `null`, so when I use it I just do `while (foo = re.exec(bar)) /* then use */ foo;`, no `lastIndex` checking

Answer (score 2):

By appending `\s+`, the pattern matches space characters.

Remove `\s+`:

```
'x y z '.match(/\w{1,3}/g)
// => ["x", "y", "z"]
```

Using `\b`, you can match at word boundary.

```
'x y z '.match(/\b\w{1,3}\b/g)
// => ["x", "y", "z"]
'x yyyyyyyyyy z '.match(/\b\w{1,3}\b/g)
// => ["x", "z"]
```

Comment: But then it'd match this incorrectly: `'x y abcdefgh '.match(/\w{1,3}/g` which results in `['x', 'y', 'abc', 'def', 'gh']`

Comment: Yes, with word boundary it'll remove `'abcdefgh'` from the result, but I need it to invalidate the whole string, because I want only matches with 3 characters max. Hence it should return null, not an array with matches in this case.

Comment: @good_computer, How about `var xs = 'x yyyy z '.match(/\w+/g); xs.length == xs.filter(function(x) { return x.length <= 3 }).length` ?

Comment: Yes, that does the job. But can it not be done in ONE regex? Such that if the string is valid all matches are returned and if not, a null.

Comment: @good_computer I think it would probably be more legible and manageable with separate steps, but I think I've found a working single solution for you. See my answer and let me know if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The regex: `/(?!.*?\w{4,}.*?)\b\w{1,3}\b/g` seems to work for me

```
var tests = ['x y z ','a b xy c pq','x y abcdefgh ','abc d rar','rawr'];

for(var i=0,c=tests.length;i<c;i++)
{
    var str = tests[i];
    console.log(str.match(/(?!.*?\w{4,}.*?)\b\w{1,3}\b/g));
}

/*
Results:

["x", "y", "z"]
["a", "b", "xy", "c", "pq"]
null
["abc", "d", "rar"]
null
*/
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. For example: `'123 123 1234' -> null`  which is correct. But, `'123 1234 123' -> ['123']` which should also return null. `'1234 123 123' -> ['123', '123']` which should also return null. It should return the array of matches ONLY when all space separated substrings are 3 characters or less, and should return null otherwise.